# PHP interface and class declaration sequence and compilation

Tags: php

Why this block works

```
interface B extends A{}
interface A{}
```

and this block works

```
class C implements A{}
interface B extends A{}
interface A{}
```

and this block does not?

```
class C implements B{}
interface B extends A{}
interface A{}
```

Comment: FYI for all, the error I get is `E_ERROR : type 1 -- Interface 'B' not found -- at line 2`.  I assume this is what the OP got too.

Comment: Class `C` definition must be after interface `B` definition. Move the first line to the last line and it will work.

Comment: @ADyson it's weird, because if you remove the `A` extension from `B`, it works... It's as if "class hoisting" only works if there's no extension on the implemented class... weird